# Help with the contour for this integral using residues

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

$$ PV \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}(x^2-1)} $$

A keyhole contour can't be used because we have a pole in the real positive axis, isn't it?

Comment: That integral diverges at $x=1$.

Comment: I'd write $u=\sqrt{x}$, $u^2=x$, $2u\,du=dx$, so the integral becomes $\displaystyle\int \frac{2\,du}{u^4-1}$ $\displaystyle=\int \frac{2\,du}{(u-1)(u+1)(u^2+1)}$.  Maybe after finding the antiderivatives I examine whether there's a principal value.  But that doesn't help find a contour, used in very different methods. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Which type of integrals does this one belong to?

Comment: A keyhole contour with indents at $1$. The integrals over the circular arcs at $1$ are strongly related to the residue of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}(z^2-1)}$ at $1$. But be careful that you don't mix up which branch of the square root to use in which half-plane for the residue.

Comment: Dear @dralion94 First of all welcome to the MSE site. I see that, although you have already asked 3 question in this site and received answers in all three of them, you have not mark a best answer in any of them. You can do it so by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer that you think is the one that helped you the most. Please [read here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) for more detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a deformed keyhole contour by providing a semicircular detour of radius $\epsilon$ along each branch.  Then consider

$$\oint_C dz \frac{z^{-1/2}}{z^2-1} $$

where $C$ is the deformed keyhole contour.  Thus, the contour integral is equal to

$$\int_{\epsilon}^{1-\epsilon} dx \frac{x^{-1/2}}{x^2-1} + i \epsilon \int_{\pi}^0 d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac{(1+\epsilon e^{i \phi})^{-1/2}}{(1+\epsilon e^{i \phi})^2-1}+\int_{1+\epsilon}^R dx \frac{x^{-1/2}}{x^2-1} \\ +i R \int_0^{2 \pi} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \frac{(1+R e^{i \theta})^{-1/2}}{(1+R e^{i \theta})^2-1} + e^{-i \pi} \int_R^{1+\epsilon} dx \frac{x^{-1/2}}{x^2-1} \\ + i \epsilon \int_{2 \pi}^{\pi} d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac{(e^{i 2 \pi}+\epsilon e^{i \phi})^{-1/2}}{(e^{i 2 \pi}+\epsilon e^{i \phi})^2-1} + e^{-i \pi} \int_{1-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} dx \frac{x^{-1/2}}{x^2-1} + i \epsilon \int_{2 \pi}^0 d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac{\epsilon^{-1/2} e^{-i \phi/2}}{\epsilon^2 e^{i 2 \phi}-1}$$

Note that there eight sections to the contour.  We take the limits as $R \to \infty$ and $\epsilon \to 0$.  As $R \to \infty$, the fourth integral vanishes.  As $\epsilon \to 0$, the eighth integral vanishes.  Also, the second integral is $-i \pi/2$ while the sixth integral is $i \pi/2$.  The first, third, fifth, and seventh integrals sum to twice the principal value of the original integral.  Thus, the contour integral is equal to, in these limits,

$$2 PV \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{x^{-1/2}}{x^2-1} $$

The contour integral is also equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the residue of the integrand at the pole $z=e^{i \pi}$, so that

$$PV \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{x^{-1/2}}{x^2-1} = i \pi \frac{e^{-i \pi/2}}{2 (-1)}= -\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Jus like mine!! ;-))

Comment: @Dr.MV: Oh snap, and here I thought that I was a trailblazer.

Comment: You are a trail blazer!!  I always like your work.  And we got the same answer.  Gee, I just hope Mathematica and WA can validate us now.

Comment: (+1) We seem to have three different presentations of the same contour integral.

Comment: @RonGordon Are the expression between parentheses in the fourth expression and the exponent in the fifth and seventh integrals right?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 7):

Make the branch cut for $\sqrt{z}$ along the positive real axis.

[image]

The integral over the entire closed curve is $2\pi i$ times the residue at $z=-1$:
$$
\begin{align}
\oint\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\sqrt{z}(z^2-1)}
&=\oint\frac1{2\sqrt{z}}\left(\frac1{z-1}-\frac1{z+1}\right)\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=2\pi i\cdot\frac i2\\[9pt]
&=-\pi\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
The integral along the grey circles vanishes as the small one shrinks and the large one grows.

As it shrinks, the integral along the upper red semicircle is $-\pi i$ times the residue in the upper half plane at $z=1$; that is, $\sqrt{1}=1$:
$$
-\pi i\cdot\frac12\tag{2}
$$
As it shrinks, the integral along the lower red semicircle is $-\pi i$ times the residue in the lower half plane at $z=1$; that is, $\sqrt{1}=-1$:
$$
-\pi i\cdot-\frac12\tag{3}
$$
Thus, the integral over the two red semicircles cancel.

The integral over the upper perforated line is
$$
\mathrm{PV}\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x}(x^2-1)}\tag{4}
$$
The integral over the lower perforated line is in the opposite direction, but $\sqrt{z}=-\sqrt{x}$, so it is also.
$$
\mathrm{PV}\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x}(x^2-1)}\tag{5}
$$
Combining these gives
$$
2\,\mathrm{PV}\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x}(x^2-1)}=-\pi\tag{6}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\mathrm{PV}\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x}(x^2-1)}=-\frac\pi2\tag{7}
$$

Comment: (+1) As usual very good job ! I am guessing you did the contour plot with mathematica right? Last time I tried I quit very soon and ended doing [this](http://i.imgur.com/Fw64h2b.png) in a design software (not bad I think). I am not very good yet at mathematica if you could send me your code for that contour plot, that will be great !

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín: actually, I did my contour plot in a program called Intaglio (it's Mac only).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reference, I work with Mac myself, I´ll certainly be taking a look at the program, hope is not to complicated though!

Comment: It is pretty easy to use. It has an interface similar to MacDraw, a simple-to-use program from long ago for the Mac.

Comment: Well thanks a lot again !! I think my life is gonna change from now on, I've always worked with corel draw to do my contour plots, and as you can see they do not ended looking half as good as yours, and the time that took me to do them was pretty long!!

Comment: What's the best plotting program (Including contours) for Windows? Any recommendations?

Comment: @Kugelblitz: since I am a Mac user, I can't really say. Aside from the fact that this sounds opinion-based, it might better be a question on its own. It might get better answers if you were able to specify certain features you were looking for.

Comment: True... 
Thank you for the Intaglio suggestion btw; I too use the Mac.

Answer (score 5):

If we interpret the integral as the Principal Value integral

$$\begin{align}
I&=\text{PV}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{1/2}(x^2-1)}\\\\
& =\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\left(\int_0^{1-\epsilon}\frac{dx}{x^{1/2}(x^2-1)}+\int_{{1+\epsilon}}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{1/2}(x^2-1)}\right)
\end{align}$$

then we may evaluate $I$ using contour integration.

---

We will analyze the integral

$$\oint_C \frac{dz}{z^{1/2}(z^2-1)}$$

where $C$ is the "keyhole" contour comprised of $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$, $C_4$, $C_5, C_6$, and $C_7$ where

$C_1$ is the integral along the real axis from $(0,0)$ to $(1-\epsilon,0)$ above the branch cut on the real axis

$C_2$ is the integral along the semi-circle $z=1+\epsilon e^{i\theta}$, above the branch cut, where $\theta$ starts at $\pi$ and ends at $0$

$C_3$ is the integral along the real axis from $(1+\epsilon,0)$ to $(R,0)$ above the branch cut on the real axis

$C_4$ is the integral along the circle $|z|=R$ from $(R,0)$ just above the branch cut to $(R,0)$ just below the branch cut

$C_5$ is the integral along the real axis from $(R,0)$ to $(1+\epsilon,0)$ below the branch cut on the real axis

$C_6$ is the integral along the semi-circle $z=1+\epsilon e^{i\theta}$, below the branch cut, where $\theta$ starts at $0$ and ends at $-\pi$

$C_7$ is the integral along the real axis from $(1-\epsilon,0)$ to $(0,0)$ below the branch cut on the real axis

> There is an eight component of the contour integral that surround the branch point, but inasmuch as this integral is trivially seen to contribute zero, we tacitly omitted it herein.
>
> ---

Note that the integral of interest $I$ is given by

$$I=\lim_{R\to \infty}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{C_1+C_3}\frac{dz}{z^{1/2}(z^2-1)}$$

and

$$I=\lim_{R\to \infty}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{C_5+C_7}\frac{dz}{z^{1/2}(z^2-1)}$$

since below the branch cut $\sqrt{z}=-\sqrt{x}$.

---

Further note that the integral over $C_4$ vanishes as $R\to \infty$.

---

We now evaluate the integrals over $C_2$ and $C_6$.  These are

$$\begin{align}
\int_{C_4}\frac{dz}{z^{1/2}(z^2-1)}&=\int_{\pi}^0\frac{i\epsilon e^{i\theta}}{(1+\epsilon e^{i\theta})^{1/2}(\epsilon e^{i\theta})(2+\epsilon e^{i\theta})}d\theta\\\\
&\to -i\pi/2 \,\,\text{as}\,\,\epsilon \to 0
\end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}
\int_{C_6}\frac{dz}{z^{1/2}(z^2-1)}&=\int_{0}^{-\pi}\frac{i\epsilon e^{i\theta}}{\left(e^{i2\pi}(1+\epsilon e^{i\theta})\right)^{1/2}(e^{i2\pi}\epsilon e^{i\theta})(1+e^{i2\pi}(1+\epsilon e^{i\theta}))}d\theta\\\\
&\to i\pi/2 \,\,\text{as}\,\,\epsilon \to 0
\end{align}$$

Therefore,

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{C_2+C_4}\frac{dz}{z^{1/2}(z^2-1)}=0$$

---

Thus, putting it all together we have

$$\begin{align}
2I&=\lim_{R\to \infty}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\oint_C \frac{dz}{z^{1/2}(z^2-1)}\\\\
&=2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z^{1/2}(z^2-1)}, z=-1\right) \\\\
&=2\pi i \frac{1}{-2i}\\\\
&=-\pi\\\\
I&=-\pi/2
\end{align}$$

Comment: I usually use a keywhole like yours when dealing with this kinds of integrals, I used [this one](http://i.imgur.com/Fw64h2b.png) to prove that 
$$
\text{P.V.} \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{-c}}{x-1} dx = \pi \cot(c \pi)
$$

Comment: (+1) I think our approaches are essentially the same. I included a diagram to try to simplify the explanation.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks!!  Coming from you that just made my day - which is one day after surgery #4.  I'm feeling pretty well considering the general anesthesia.

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín Neat solution to the reference post!!  +1 on that one.

Answer (score 0):

If you set $y=\sqrt{x}$ you have:

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{2ydy}{y(y^4-1)}=2\int_0^\infty\frac{dy}{y^4-1}$$

Since you are integrating an even function you can write it as:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dy}{y^4-1}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dy}{(y-1)(y+1)(y-i)(y+i)}$$

Now you can easily use contour integration to get:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dy}{y^4-1}=2i\pi \lim_{y\to i}\frac{y-i}{y^4-1}=-\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Using Sokhotsky-Plemelj theorem twice to get the principal value:

$$\int \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)+i\epsilon}dz+i\pi f(z_0)=P\int \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)}dz $$

where $z_0=\pm i$. So you should have:

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}(x^2-1)}=\frac{\pi}{2}+i\pi\left(-\frac{i}{4} + \frac{i}{4}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Please tell me if I made some mistakes (likely)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The Sokhotsky-Plemlj theorem is unknown for me so it must exist some way to do it by residues without using it.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\mrm{P.V.}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over
\root{x}\pars{x^{2} - 1}}} =
\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over
\root{x}\pars{x - 1 + \ic 0^{+}}\pars{x + 1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,\Re\int_{\infty}^{0}{\ic\,\dd y \over
\root{y}\expo{\ic\pi/4}\pars{\ic y - 1 + \ic 0^{+}}
\pars{\ic y + 1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ic\expo{-\ic\pi/4}\, \over
\root{y}\pars{1 + y^{2}}}\,\dd y =
-\,{\root{2} \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{y^{-1/2} \over
1 + y^{2}}\,\dd y
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{\root{2} \over 4}\int_{0}^{\infty}{y^{\color{red}{1/4} - 1} \over
1 + y}\,\dd y
\end{align}
Note that $\ds{{1 \over 1 + y} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\color{red}{\Gamma\pars{1 + k}}
\,{\pars{-y}^{k} \over k!}}$. With *Ramanujan's MT*:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\mrm{P.V.}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over
\root{x}\pars{x^{2} - 1}}} =
-\,{\root{2} \over 4}\Gamma\pars{\color{red}{1 \over 4}}
\Gamma\pars{1 - \color{red}{1 \over 4}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{\root{2} \over 4}\,{\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi/4}} =
\bbx{-\,{\pi \over 2}} \\ &
\end{align}